# Android: How to copy one word from a block of texts to search for definition

Tags: android, dictionary, textview

I am developing an Android application and I have displayed a story using TextView. I want that if the user tap on a particular word, it will copy that word and send it to the dictionary within the application and search for its definition. How do I do that? How do I know what word is tapped by the user since the TextView consists of around hundred words.

Answer (score 0):

In same case I used array of textViews. To make it this way you should prepare text, for example split text with " ". 
The second way is to use WebView, text as html doc and some javascript.

Comment: there would be way too much textViews, moreover, the story is generated in run-time and I don't know how many words there are in the story -> it's not static. Also, not all words will be clickable, only those words found in the dictionary will be.

Comment: I guess it does not matter q-ty of textViews. Anyway 100 word is not big q-ty. Difficulty is if you need change words inside text.